# Delete Files Immediately, using AppleScript

Tags: file, applescript

I am a novice when it comes to using applescripts. I am wanting to be able to delete the contents of a folder immediately after some previous scripts have been run. I do not know if this is possible, but if it is, I would greatly appreciate the help in providing this solution.

Comment: The `delete` command of the Finder moves the file(s) to the trash folder. To delete files immediately you need to use the `rm` command of the shell: `do shell script "/bin/rm ... "`

Answer (score 4):

```
tell application id ("com.apple.SystemEvents") ¬
        to tell the folder ("~/path/to/folder") ¬
        to delete (files whose visible = true)
```

**Warning:** There is no confirmation before or after this command has completed its action.  The files will be deleted ***immediately*** and will ***not*** be recoverable.

`files` specifically excludes folders.  Substitute with the term `folders` to delete only folders.  Substitute with the term `items` to delete files *and* folders contained in the folder at the specified path.

`~/` is recognised short-form denoting the user's home folder, so *`~/path/to/folder`* is equivalent to *`/Users/<you>/path/to/folder`*.

The `whose visible` filter is spares hidden files that one might wish to keep if they are likely to be important; otherwise, simply amend the final line to `delete the files` to delete both hidden and non-hidden files.  `delete the items` will scrub everything inside that folder.

---

<sub>**Special cases:**</sub>

<sub>**•** If the target is a symbolic link to a folder, target `the folder (path of item "~/path/to/folder")`.</sub>

<sup>**•** If the target is a *Finder* alias that points to a folder, retrieve the original path of the folder: `tell app id "com.apple.finder" to tell the alias file ("/Users/<you>/path/to/folder"1 as POSIX file) to set pathToFolder to its original item as text`.  The variable `pathToFolder` can be used in place of the quoted string path in the *System Events* block that otherwise remains the same.</sup>  
 <sub><sup>1</sup>The shorthand `~/` cannot be used in a_ Finder *block, so the fully-formed, absolute path will need to be used.*</sub>

Comment: Is it somehow possible to execute this with administrator privileges? In my specific case, I'd want the script to delete an installed app from within the `/Applications` folder.

Comment: @emkey08 Do you mean without the need to enter an administrator password ?  I highly suspect this would not be possible, and I do not know a way.  Let me know if you learn otherwise.

Comment: No, I mean **with** entering the administrator password. It's possible to do this with `do shell script "rm -rf /path/to/folder" with administrator privileges`, but I was just wondering whether the same thing can also be somehow done with `tell application "System Events"`. The `with administrator privileges` clause apparently doesn't work with the `tell` command...

Comment: @emkey08, the way I know how to achieve this uses an Objective-C `NSFileManager` method that unfortunately isn't something that can be called from AppleScript (it requires the use of a completion handler that AppleScript doesn't have the means to emulate). So this might be one instance where you may have to settle for using a `do shell script` hack as you've described, or switching to another language such as Obj-C or Swift in which you can provide the necessary completion handler. :o(